# Import an old LibGDX / Eclipse project to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, libgdx

I'm trying to import an old LibGDX Android game to Android Studio. I last worked on it using Eclipse around a year and a half ago, and the project looks like this:

[image]

Where AndroidGame-core is the game logic and AndroidGame-android contains Android components like `AndroidManifest` and `resources`. Both AndroidGame-android and AndroidGame-core have a `build.gradle` file.

I imported it into Android Studio in this way: File -> New -> Import project then simply selected the directory containing the 3 folders above.

This imported both AndroidGame-core and AndroidGame-android into Android Studio as required - however, everything is red and I can't find any `build.gradle` file or assets folder (containing things such as sprites).

AndroidStudio is also giving me a message "This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system."

Comment: Why not to setup new project in Android Studio and then just copy sources (packaged, classes...) there?

Comment: Yeah that's the easiest way.